# Changing to polar coordinates bring the differential equation to $\Phi(\phi,\rho,\rho'(\phi)) = 0$ form.

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, implicit-function

I have a differential equation $y'=\dfrac{x+y}{x-y}$ and the problem says to change to polar coordinate system by assuming $x = \rho\cos\phi$, $y = \rho\sin\phi$ and $\rho=\rho(\phi)$ and bring the equation to $\Phi(\phi,\rho,\rho'(\phi)) = 0$ form. The answer is $\rho'(\phi)=\rho(\phi)$. This problem is under "Implicit Functions" in the book, so I suppose I should use the Implicit-function theorem. But I don't see what I can get from that. I did substitute and tried to simplify, but in vain. The only way I see to solve this after substitution is by applying trigonometry, but every time either $\rho(\phi)$ or $\rho'(\phi)$ are multiplied by some other trigonometric function (that can't be simplified to a constant) and it seems that just trigonometry is not enough. Could you explain how such problems are solved? I couldn't find examples on the internet either.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Multiply out the numerator and re-arrange to get
$$
xy'-y=x+yy'
$$
or more suggestive
$$
x\,dy-y\,dx=x\,dx+y\,dy
$$

Under polar coordinates this reads also as
$$
ρ^2\,dϕ =ρ\,dρ 
$$
One can reason that in most situations this can be canceled to
$$
\frac{dρ}{dϕ}=ρ
$$
with an implied change in the independent variable.

Comment: Thanks a lot, I checked by hand the passage and got the result. But how can I see which form will be easier to simplify when converting to polar coordinates?

Comment: You don't, without the hint. In this equation the standard path would be the homogeneous approach, $y(x)=xu(x)$. Another path is to change to a different independent variable so that the resulting system becomes linear, $$\pmatrix{\dot x\\\dot y}=\pmatrix{1&-1\\1&1}\pmatrix{x\\y},$$ where now one can recognize that the system matrix corresponds to the complex number $1+i$. There the new independent turns out to be the angle, but that was not built-in from the approach.

Answer (score 1):

$$y'=\dfrac{x+y}{x-y}$$
$$\dfrac {dy}{dx}=\dfrac{x+y}{x-y}$$
Be carefull and apply the chain rule:
$$\dfrac {dy}{dt}\dfrac {dt}{dx}=\dfrac{x+y}{x-y}$$
$$\dfrac {dy}{dt}=\dfrac {dx}{dt}\dfrac{x+y}{x-y}$$
Substitute now $y=r(t)\sin t$:
$$\dfrac {dr(t) \sin t}{dt}=\dfrac{\cos t+ \sin t}{\cos t-\sin t}\dfrac {dr(t) \cos(t)}{dt}$$
$$r' \sin t+r \cos t=\dfrac{\cos t+ \sin t}{\cos t-\sin t}(r'\cos t -r \sin t)$$
$$(r' \sin t+r \cos t)(\cos t -\sin t)=(\cos t+ \sin t)(r'\cos t -r \sin t)$$
This is simple trigonometry. It should simplify nicely and give you Lutz Lehmann's nice answer.
$$r'=r$$